# Angular: I keep on getting error 400: bad request "One or more validation error occured" when using httpPost

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular13

> Service.ts

```
  addTankValues(data:any) {
return this.http.post(this.TankApiUrl + "...", data).pipe(
  tap(()=>{
    this.RefreshRequired.next();
  })
);
```

}

> Subscribing to the httpPost:

```
 SaveTV(){
if(this.TVForm.valid){
  console.log(this.TVForm.value);
  this.service.addTankValues(this.TVForm.value).subscribe(result=>{
    this.TVFormresp=result;
    console.log(this.TVFormresp);
    this.alert = true;
    this.TVForm.reset();
  });
}else{
  console.log("form not valid");
}
```

I keep on getting 400 error: bad request when sending post request to my asp.net backend. "one or more validation error occurs.

Comment: Usually any HTTP 4xx indicates problem on the client side. 
Are you sure that you are sending all the required parameters from client side to the server ?

To troubleshoot - You can try postman ( or anything similar to interact with backend ) and send the exact request object to the backend. I strongly believe that there must be some parameter missing which has been marked as mandatory by backend.

Comment: Do you know if I convert my object to parson/json, will it accept my object? I dont know how to use headers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure your http header options

```js
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

2. Apps often send data to a server with a POST request when submitting a form. In the following example, the HeroesService makes an HTTP POST request when adding a hero to the database.
   app/heroes/heroes.service.ts (addHero)

```js
    
/** POST: add a new hero to the database */
addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

The HttpClient.post() method is similar to get() in that it has a type parameter, which you can use to specify that you expect the server to return data of a given type. The method takes a resource URL and two additional parameters:

Taken from https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

fIXED this using cors

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).